# Does function: $ f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} $ exist for these statements

Tags: functions, logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

Does function: $ f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} $ exist, such that this statement is true:
$$(\forall{x} \in \mathbb{Z}:f(x) \geq 2)\Rightarrow(\forall{x}\in \mathbb{Z}:f(x)<10)$$
and this statement is false:
$$ \forall{x} \in \mathbb{Z}:(f(x) \geq 2\Rightarrow f(x)<10) $$
Now I understand that the second statement is stronger. But I am not sure how I would go about proving whether the function exists or not on paper.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Choose $f(0) := 0$ and $\forall x \in \mathbb Z\setminus \{0\}: f(x) := 10$

Comment: The second statement can be read as $\forall x \in \mathbb Z: (f(x) < 2 \vee f(x)  < 10)$ which is false.

Comment: Do you know the equivalence between $p \Rightarrow q$ and $(\neg p) \vee q$ for propositions $p$ and $q$?

Comment: @Moritz I do, even if I forgot, its easy to check by writing it down into a table with 0/1's.

Comment: Try writing down the first function $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$ that comes to mind. It will probably satisfy the requirements -- unless it is constant, in which case try the first _non-constant_ function $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$ that comes to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the following truth table for the conditional $p\Rightarrow q$:

### p q | ( p => q )

T T |   T
T F |   F
F T |   T
F F |   T

You see that you can make an implication of the form $p\Rightarrow q$ true by choosing $p$ to be false (and $q$ to have any truth value).
To make the claim
$$(\forall{x} \in \mathbb{Z}:f(x) \geq 2)\Rightarrow(\forall{x}\in \mathbb{Z}:f(x)<10)$$
true, I can thus choose a function $f$, such that $\exists x\in\Bbb{Z}\colon f(x)<2$ is a true statement, i.e. the function should take a value less than $2$ at at least one integer point.
You also want
$$\forall{x} \in \mathbb{Z}:(f(x) \geq 2\Rightarrow f(x)<10)$$
to be false. I can make the conditional $p\Rightarrow q$ false by choosing $p$ to be true and $q$ to be false, so I need at least one integer point $x$, such that $f(x)\geq 2$ is true, but $f(x)<10$ is false (i.e. $f(x)\geq 10$ is true). This can be done by simply choosing a point $x$, such that $f(x)\geq 10$.

Summa summarum, I need a point $x_1$, such that $f(x_1)<2$, and another point $x_2$, such that $f(x_2)\geq 10$. Any function with these properties works.

Answer (score 2):

In order for the second statement to be false there has to be some $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)\ge 2$ and yet $\neg(f(x_0)<10)$. That is, $f(x_0) \ge 10$.

This means that the *conclusion* of the first statement will be false, so the only way to make the entire implication true is to make sure that the *hypothesis* is false too. Therefore there must be an $x_1$ such that $f(x_1)<2$.

Thus we see that your requirements will be satisfied as long as there is at least one function value that is $\ge 10$ and one function value that is $<2$.

You'll have considerable freedom in choosing such a function.